# How can I generate dates of a certain Gregorian year to Hijri

Tags: javascript, c#, kendo-ui, calendar, hijri

I want to make an auto adaptation or generation of days of year, from Gregorian to Hijri.

I mean that you want to select or write the year as example:

select 2015:

- Get all the days of  2015  in Gregorian and  then its convert to Hijrim and present the list of hijri.

so you want to return to  2 list  list1 gregoriad days list vs another list2 hijhri

I want this in JavaScript and using kendo-ui framework to view it.

Comment: are hijri dates always same with gregorian calendar? i mean are two dates in say january 1, 1770 and that date in hijri same in the year 2015?

Comment: for example to day is 25/5/2015 gregorian  then in hijri is 6 sha3ban 1436

Comment: Do you have the sample code of what you have tried so far that isn't working?

Comment: no, i have database needs : dates in gregorian vs dates on higri

Answer (score 3):

Kendo UI [only](http://www.telerik.com/forums/datepicker-buddhist-year#jdSv5B8-hkimNxpozh10qQ) supports the [Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar). There don't seem to be plans to add any others.

You could use .NET to convert the date.

```
public string ConvertDateCalendar(DateTime DateConv, ECalenderTypes calendar, string DateLangCulture)
{
    System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo DTFormat;
    DateLangCulture = DateLangCulture.ToLower();
    /// We can't have the hijri date writen in English. We will get a runtime error

    if (calendar == ECalenderTypes.Hijri && DateLangCulture.StartsWith("en-"))
    {
        DateLangCulture = "ar-sa";
    }

    /// Set the date time format to the given culture
    DTFormat = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(DateLangCulture, false).DateTimeFormat;

    /// Set the calendar property of the date time format to the given calendar
    switch (calendar)
    {
        case ECalenderTypes.Hijri:
            DTFormat.Calendar = new System.Globalization.HijriCalendar();
            break;

        case ECalenderTypes.Gregorian:
            DTFormat.Calendar = new System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar();
            break;

        default:
            return "";
    }

    /// We format the date structure to whatever we want 
    DTFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    return (DateConv.Date.ToString("f", DTFormat));
}
```

And then:

```
ConvertDateCalendar("01/01/2015", ECalenderTypes.Gregorian, "en-US");
ConvertDateCalendar("01/01/2015", ECalenderTypes.Hijri, "en-US");
```

**JavaScript**

```
function gmod(n,m){
    return ((n%m)+m)%m;
}
function getDate(adjust){
    var today = new Date();
    if(adjust) {
        adjustmili = 1000*60*60*24 * adjust; 
        todaymili = today.getTime() + adjustmili;
        today = new Date(todaymili);
    }
    day = today.getDate();
    month = today.getMonth();
    year = today.getFullYear();
    m = month+1;
    y = year;
    if(m<3) {
        y -= 1;
        m += 12;
    }

    a = Math.floor(y/100.);
    b = 2-a+Math.floor(a/4.);
    if(y<1583) b = 0;
    if(y==1582) {
        if(m>10)  b = -10;
        if(m==10) {
            b = 0;
            if(day>4) b = -10;
        }
    }

    jd = Math.floor(365.25*(y+4716))+Math.floor(30.6001*(m+1))+day+b-1524;

    b = 0;
    if(jd>2299160){
        a = Math.floor((jd-1867216.25)/36524.25);
        b = 1+a-Math.floor(a/4.);
    }
    bb = jd+b+1524;
    cc = Math.floor((bb-122.1)/365.25);
    dd = Math.floor(365.25*cc);
    ee = Math.floor((bb-dd)/30.6001);
    day =(bb-dd)-Math.floor(30.6001*ee);
    month = ee-1;
    if(ee>13) {
        cc += 1;
        month = ee-13;
    }
    year = cc-4716;

    wd = gmod(jd+1,7)+1;

    iyear = 10631./30.;
    epochastro = 1948084;
    epochcivil = 1948085;

    shift1 = 8.01/60.;

    z = jd-epochastro;
    cyc = Math.floor(z/10631.);
    z = z-10631*cyc;
    j = Math.floor((z-shift1)/iyear);
    iy = 30*cyc+j;
    z = z-Math.floor(j*iyear+shift1);
    im = Math.floor((z+28.5001)/29.5);
    if(im==13) im = 12;
    id = z-Math.floor(29.5001*im-29);

    var myRes = new Array(8);

    myRes[0] = day; //calculated day (CE)
    myRes[1] = month-1; //calculated month (CE)
    myRes[2] = year; //calculated year (CE)
    myRes[3] = jd-1; //julian day number
    myRes[4] = wd-1; //weekday number
    myRes[5] = id; //islamic date
    myRes[6] = im-1; //islamic month
    myRes[7] = iy; //islamic year

    return myRes;
}
function writeHijriDate(adjustment) {
    var wdNames = new Array("Ahad","Ithnin","Thulatha","Arbaa","Khams","Jumuah","Sabt");
    var iMonthNames = new Array("Muharram","Safar","Rabi'ul Awwal","Rabi'ul Akhir", "Jumadal Ula","Jumadal Akhira","Rajab","Sha'ban", "Ramadan","Shawwal","Dhul Qa'ada","Dhul Hijja");
    var iDate = getDate(adjustment);
    var outputHijriDate = wdNames[iDate[4]] + ", " + iDate[5] + " " + iMonthNames[iDate[6]] + " " + iDate[7] + " AH";
    return outputHijriDate;
}
```

Usage (converts current date):

```
writeHijriDate(1);
```

Comment: Ah, I missed that. :) I've added some JavaScript code, too.

Answer (score 1):

Hirji calendar is not supported with Kendo UI.

Comment: can you implement  without kendo ui

Comment: can  you use angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all
I found someone write a simple implementation for the Islamic calender(Hijri) in Javascript

http://xsoh.github.com/Hijri.js
its consist the convert from hijri to gregorian and Vice versaز

Answer (score 0):

The conversion is very easy using `Intl` object ([read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl)), as following:

```js
a = new Date();
localeFormat= 'ar-SA-islamic-umalqura';
Intl.DateTimeFormat(localeFormat).format(a)
```