# how to add the Hijri calendar to FullCalendar

Tags: reactjs, calendar, fullcalendar, hijri

I am using FullCalendar in react .I need to be able to add the Hijri calendar to my calendar.in view Month and listMonth .I need to startDate in the calendar according to the Hijri calendar, not the Gregorian calendar

Comment: This is not supported (yet): https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/2105 . Add your vote to the feature if you're interested.

Comment: you could use `Intl` object as following:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74241986/7045119