# React-Native Hijri calendar library

Tags: react-native, datepicker, calendar, hijri

I need iOS & Android Date-picker component specifically for React-Native. When I searched on the internet, there is no up-to-date library available. Has anyone encountered this problem before? What solution can you suggest? I tried many modules but couldn't find any up-to-date library.

Comment: this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/74241986/7045119